# jQuery fadeOut & fadeIn not working properly

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('#oldLoginProblem').fadeOut();
$('#newLoginProblem').fadeOut();
$('#newLoginProblem').fadeIn();
```

It runs each time I press a button.

In the beginning, it'll look like this:

`foobar`

But when I press my button and run that code, it looks like this:

`foobar`

`foobar2`

The first element doesn't disappear, it remains. The second element just shows up below, as if I have a simple .show(). Also, there is no fading occurring in any way. How can I solve this?

Comment: You should to post your HTML and entire jQuery so we can see what's going on.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p3469/ try this

Comment: @rsplak - Don't use delays! They're unreliable. You should use callbacks to chain animation properly instead. http://jsfiddle.net/p3469/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you want your animations to happen in a sequence, you need to trigger them using callbacks (otherwise they will all trigger at once and look like a mess):

```
$('#oldLoginProblem').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#newLoginProblem').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#newLoginProblem').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

It also looks like you might have a bad ID somewhere in your markup (since the first piece of content isn't fading out) but it's impossible to tell without an example of your markup.